# Align memory in c program with external assembly for AVX

Tags: c, assembly, alignment, avx

i have this declaration in my c program

```
u_int64_t *x ;
x = (u_int64_t*)calloc(length, 8);
```

and want to replace it with an instruction that aligns the allocated 8-byte blocks to be able to use aligned AVX instructions such as vmovdqa and i used calloc because it initializes the blocks to 0 which is what i need.
Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23092621/why-is-there-no-aligned-calloc-in-c11

Comment: Use `aligned_alloc`.  Note that `vmovdqa` moves a 16 byte block.  For an 8 byte block, 8 byte alignment is sufficient in all cases.